# Save after importing from swagger causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, wso2

I have WSO2 1.7.0 setup on a local Ubuntu 14.04 using Oracle Server JRE 1.7.0_72. I've created a new API successfully however when I attempt to import the implementation from our Swagger docs (also hosted locally) I get this error in the logs and a popup alert in the management console with the content "null".

Steps:

1. Create new API
2. Import implementation from Swagger
3. Save

The error in the logs is:

```
RROR - add:jag org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#119)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_6(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:119)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_29(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:95)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c1._c_anonymous_2(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:77)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c1.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c1._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:18)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c1.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c1.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c1.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.parseResourceConfig(APIProviderHostObject.java:818)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPIDesign(APIProviderHostObject.java:563)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not specified any operations in your swagger document which is leading to this exception.

Could you verify your swagger document format against [this](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/)?

Comment: I know the swagger docs are correct as they render correctly, can be tested and the json lints.

I've put the docs online here as an example: http://81.155.25.33:3000/docs/

Comment: Cannot access the online swagger doc at the moment, can you provide an alternative permanent location?

Comment: Trying to get them back online. Currently having issues getting this public